# BrowseForFolder-Dialog: center and make TopMost

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I have a `Winforms Gui` with a `BrowseForFolder-Dialog`.

Is there any way to make this dialog the **TopMost** window and/or **center** it on the screen?

```
$getfolder = New-Object -com shell.application
$foldername = $getfolder.BrowseForFolder(0,"Text",16,"")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the owner handle.

```
$handle = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
$getfolder = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$foldername = $getfolder.BrowseForFolder([int]$handle, "Text", 16, "")
```

But it is a mixture of COM and .NET. I recommend the following solution

```
$win32WindowDefinition = @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Win32Window : IWin32Window
{
    public Win32Window(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $win32WindowDefinition -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms.dll 

$ownerHandle = New-Object Win32Window -ArgumentList ([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
$folderBrowserDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$dialogResult = $folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog($ownerHandle)
if ($dialogResult -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $folderName = $folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
}
```

from http://poshcode.org/2002

Comment: The first one works great. I need the COM variant because of the possible option-flags. 
Is it possible to center the dialog on the screen or set the position?

Comment: There is no way to set the position. Possible solution is creating custom dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx), to show it as top-most and at the center of screen, it's enough to pass a `TopMost` form to its `ShowDialog` method.

**C# Example**

```
var f = new FolderBrowserDialog();
f.ShowDialog(new Form() { TopMost = true}); 
this.Activate();
```

**Powershell Example**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
$folder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -property @{TopMost = $True}
$folder.ShowDialog($form)
```

Comment: Thanks but how does this translate to powershell?

Comment: Your question has `C#` tag also. Anyway, I posted Powershell code too :)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I'm able to translate C# to powershell, but in this case I could not. 
But the forms- FolderBrowser is not quite the same as the one I used above. I need to be able to A) display a text inside the dialog and b) have the input-box inside where one can manually enter paths. With the shell.application-folderbrowser you can configure that with the BrowseInfo -flags.

Comment: The text can be set using `Description` property but the `TextBox` can not.